# UITableView float around image (view)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that covers the whole screen, with a lot of cells.
On the view that holds the `UITableView` I want to display an `UIImage` at the top right corner.
This `UIImage` (or `UIImageView`) is fixed on the `UIView` - it is not part of the tableView (in the z order it is over the tableView).

It is possible to let the `UITableView` float around this image, even when scrolling?

Below an image of my desired structure. Imagine that they are more cells even under der image. The cells (or `UILabels`) that are covered by the image should be truncated (or do a line break).

Is this possible? Currently I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can play with table view's content offset to determine which cells reach your image and then update constraints for these cell's objects. Do you realy think this is a good UI?

Comment: In the real App it should look nicer than the image in the question of course. I am not sure if this UI is good or bad. Currently I don't find it so bad.

Comment: I agree with @MartinKoles, [this is a bad idea](https://vine.co/v/Ma0Ph7JYI1e) (make sure you turn the sound on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to adjust the trailing space constraint of a label on your custom table view cell based on tableview's scrollview delegate method. You need to check if your cell is in the area of your imageView and then adjust the constraint. You also need to adjust the constraint in your cellForRowAtIndexPath for the initial layout.

**Storyboard**

[image]

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyCell.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.myLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc.";

    if (indexPath.row >=3 && indexPath.row <= 5) {

        cell.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = 168;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSUInteger count = 0;

    for (MyCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {

        if (count >= 3 && count <= 6) {

            cell.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = 168.0;
        } else {

            cell.trailingSpaceConstraint.constant = 20.0;
        }
        count++;
    }
}

@end
```

**MyCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *trailingSpaceConstraint;

@end
```

**Output**

[image]

In this sample you need to use custom ViewController, add tableView and imageView, hook tableView's delegate and datasource and outlet. You also need to add custom subclass of UITableViewCell (MyCell) and hook outlets of the cell's label and the trailing space constraint.

The check at scrollViewDidScroll for rows is quick and dirty. Probably a better solution might be to check which cells are touching the imageView rect in indexPathsForRowsInRect.